# How far can a player jump while running backwards?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I watched Skeppy's running backwards video, and noticed that players could jump two blocks while running backwards. I have tried doing this, but I can only *barely* reach two blocks with a jump. Can players jump more than two blocks when running backward, and if so, what is the limit?

Comment: Which game are you actually talking about, MCJava or MCBE? Also, you probably mean "walk backwards", or did you find some way to actually run backwards?

Comment: I mean just hitting the back button, not sprinting backward.

Comment: You made no changes to this from when it was closed. You should make changes to the question or go onto the meta site to see what changes you should make before trying to reopen the question.

Comment: @Robbie I have not tried to reopen this post. It may have been someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. I just tried it and the maximum amount is 3. 3 Blocks. (Without any potion)
4 Blocks, with Speed I Potion.
5 Blocks, With Speed II Potion.
4 Blocks, With Jump I Potion.
5 Blocks, With Jump II Potion.

That means that you can jump backwards without potions at a MAX of 3, While with potions you can get a MAX of 5.

Comment: Is this with or without Speed or Jump Boost?

Comment: Thank you for making me notice! I will try it with Jump Boost (if possible) and Speed I, II, and III. And then I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, so this three block jump IS without speed?

Comment: True, It is without Any other effect

Comment: Here I tried with all other potions and Here are the results.